# What does "those are the breaks" mean?

Tags: idioms, phrase-meaning, conversation

I remarked to a friend, "It's too bad I have to wake up early," and he responded "those are the breaks."

What does this mean? Isn't it a bad thing to wake up late, which would be the opposite of a break?

Comment: This meaning of *break* isn't necessarily good. You can have a [*"lucky break"*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lucky+break) or a ["*bad break"*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bad-break).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZDUEilS5M4 should sum it up nicely.

Answer (score 4):

- That’s the way things turn out (used to express resigned acceptance of a situation).

From http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/break

The phrase is way down in the phrases section. It may have originated from billiards, see definition 7, as in if you have a bad run of breaks, you just have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the slang use of *[the breaks](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20breaks)* meaning :

> Bad luck, a damn shame, or an unfortunate occurrence.

Source: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+breaks

Examples:

> At the laundromat:
>
> Doc: "What up dogg." 
>   Timmy: "Nothing much. I lost a quarter under the washing machine a couple minutes ago." 
>   Doc: "That's the breaks."
>
> A week later:
>
> Doc: "What up dogg." 
>   Timmy: "Didn't you hear? I lost my job and my wife left me for the mailman. Oh yeah, and my house burned down during Thanksgiving dinner and my entire family died. What a terrible tragedy!" 
>   Doc: "That's the breaks."